# How can I incorporate PReLU in a quantized model?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to quantize a model which uses `PReLU`. Replacing `PReLU` with `ReLU` is not possible as it drastically affects the network performance to the point its useless.

As far as I know, `PReLU` is not supported in Pytorch when it comes to quantization. So I tried to rewrite this module manually and implement the multiplication and additions using `torch.FloatFunctional()` to get around this limitation.

This is what I have come up so far:

```py
class PReLU_Quantized(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, prelu_object):
        super().__init__()
        self.weight = prelu_object.weight
        self.quantized_op = nn.quantized.FloatFunctional()
        self.quant = torch.quantization.QuantStub()
        self.dequant = torch.quantization.DeQuantStub()

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # inputs = torch.max(0, inputs) + self.weight * torch.min(0, inputs)    
        self.weight = self.quant(self.weight)
        weight_min_res = self.quantized_op.mul(self.weight, torch.min(inputs)[0])
        inputs = self.quantized_op.add(torch.max(inputs)[0], weight_min_res).unsqueeze(0)
        self.weight = self.dequant(self.weight)
        return inputs
```

and for the replacement :

```
class model(nn.Module):
     def __init__(self)
         super().__init__()
         .... 
        self.prelu = PReLU()
        self.prelu_q = PReLU_Quantized(self.prelu)
         ....
```

Basically, I read the learned parameter of the existing prelu module, and run the calculation myself in a new module. The module seems to be working in the sense, its not failing the whole application.

However, in order to assess whether my implementation is actually correct and yields the same result as the original module, I tried to test it.
Here is a counterpart for normal models (i.e. not quantized model):
For some reason, the error between the actual `PReLU` and my implementation is very large!

Here are sample diffs in different layers:

```py
diff : 1.1562038660049438
diff : 0.02868632599711418
diff : 0.3653906583786011
diff : 1.6100226640701294
diff : 0.8999372720718384
diff : 0.03773299604654312
diff : -0.5090572834014893
diff : 0.1654307246208191
diff : 1.161868691444397
diff : 0.026089997962117195
diff : 0.4205571115016937
diff : 1.5337920188903809
diff : 0.8799554705619812
diff : 0.03827812895178795
diff : -0.40296515822410583
diff : 0.15618863701820374
```

and the diff is calculated like this in the forward pass:

```py
def forward(self, x):
    residual = x
    out = self.bn0(x)
    out = self.conv1(out)
    out = self.bn1(out)

    out = self.prelu(out)
    out2 = self.prelu2(out)
    print(f'diff : {( out - out2).mean().item()}')

    out = self.conv2(out)
...
```

This is the normal implementation which I used on ordinary model (i.e. not quantized!) to asses whether it produces correct result and then move on to quantized version:

```py
class PReLU_2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, prelu_object):
        super().__init__()
        self.prelu_weight = prelu_object.weight
        self.weight = self.prelu_weight

    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.weight
        tmin, _ = torch.min(inputs,dim=0)
        tmax, _ = torch.max(inputs,dim=0)
        weight_min_res = torch.mul(x, tmin)
        inputs = torch.add(tmax, weight_min_res)
        inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(0)
        return inputs
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! I made a huge mistake in the very begining. I needed to calculate

```
PReLU(x)=max(0,x)+a∗min(0,x)
```

or
[image]
and not the actual `torch.min`! or `torch.max`! which doesn't make any sense!
Here is the final solution for normal models (i.e not quantized)!:

```py
class PReLU_2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, prelu_object):
        super().__init__()
        self.prelu_weight = prelu_object.weight
        self.weight = self.prelu_weight

    def forward(self, inputs):
        pos = torch.relu(inputs)
        neg = -self.weight * torch.relu(-inputs)
        inputs = pos + neg
        return inputs
```

and this is the quantized version :

```py
class PReLU_Quantized(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, prelu_object):
        super().__init__()
        self.prelu_weight = prelu_object.weight
        self.weight = self.prelu_weight
        self.quantized_op = nn.quantized.FloatFunctional()
        self.quant = torch.quantization.QuantStub()
        self.dequant = torch.quantization.DeQuantStub()

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # inputs = max(0, inputs) + alpha * min(0, inputs) 
        self.weight = self.quant(self.weight)
        weight_min_res = self.quantized_op.mul(-self.weight, torch.relu(-inputs))
        inputs = self.quantized_op.add(torch.relu(inputs), weight_min_res)
        inputs = self.dequant(inputs)
        self.weight = self.dequant(self.weight)
        return inputs
```

Side note:
I also had a typo where I was calculating the diff :

```py
    out = self.prelu(out)
    out2 = self.prelu2(out)
    print(f'diff : {( out - out2).mean().item()}')

    out = self.conv2(out)
```

needs to be

```py
    out1 = self.prelu(out)
    out2 = self.prelu2(out)
    print(f'diff : {( out1 - out2).mean().item()}')
    out = self.conv2(out1)
```

### Update:

In case you face issues in quantization, you may try this [version](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/41640#issuecomment-667344109) :

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn.quantized as nnq
from torch.quantization import fuse_modules


class QPReLU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_parameters=1, init: float = 0.25):
        super(QPReLU, self).__init__()
        self.num_parameters = num_parameters
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(num_parameters).fill_(init))
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.f_mul_neg_one1 = nnq.FloatFunctional()
        self.f_mul_neg_one2 = nnq.FloatFunctional()
        self.f_mul_alpha = nnq.FloatFunctional()
        self.f_add = nnq.FloatFunctional()
        self.quant = torch.quantization.QuantStub()
        self.dequant = torch.quantization.DeQuantStub()
        self.quant2 = torch.quantization.QuantStub()
        self.quant3 = torch.quantization.QuantStub()
        # self.dequant2 = torch.quantization.QuantStub()
        self.neg_one = torch.Tensor([-1.0])
        
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.quant(x)
        
        # PReLU, with modules only
        x1 = self.relu1(x)
        
        neg_one_q = self.quant2(self.neg_one)
        weight_q = self.quant3(self.weight)
        x2 = self.f_mul_alpha.mul(
            weight_q, self.f_mul_neg_one2.mul(
                self.relu2(
                    self.f_mul_neg_one1.mul(x, neg_one_q),
                ),
            neg_one_q)
        )
        
        x = self.f_add.add(x1, x2)
        x = self.dequant(x)
        return x
    
m1 = nn.PReLU()
m2 = QPReLU()

# check correctness in fp
for i in range(10):
    data = torch.randn(2, 2) * 1000
    assert torch.allclose(m1(data), m2(data))

# toy model
class M(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(M, self).__init__()
        self.prelu = QPReLU()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.prelu(x)
        return x
    
# quantize it
m = M()
m.qconfig = torch.quantization.default_qconfig
torch.quantization.prepare(m, inplace=True)
# calibrate
m(torch.randn(4, 4))
# convert
torch.quantization.convert(m, inplace=True)
# run some data through
res = m(torch.randn(4, 4))
print(res)
```

and make sure to read the ralted notes [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/41640#issuecomment-668108514)